# How to get gcm.notification.body field in gcm push notification payload

Tags: json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, http-post, postman

I'm making set of scripts in kotlin for testing push notifications in order to refactor notification-related legacy code. 
I need to send post request to gcm server with such payload that would result in notification that arrives at my phone containing field "gcm.notification.body" and I cant seem to be able to do it. 
Currently I'm trying to figure out the payload by using Postman. "Closest" I got is "gcm.notification.data" and "fcm.notification.body".

First with this request body:

```
{  
    "to":  "someDeviceToken",
    "notification":{
        "data":{
            "title": "Title supported",
            "message": "Notification Message",
            "type": "example",
            "id": 345,
            "priority": 1,
            "data": {
                "images": [ 
                    "https://someimage.com/image.png"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second with this one:

```
{  
    "to":  "someDeviceToken",
    "data":{
        "fcm.notification.body":{
            "title": "Title supported",
            "message": "Notification Message",
            "type": "example",
            "id": 345,
            "priority": 1,
            "data": {
                "images": [ 
                    "https://someimage.com/image.png"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find anything anywhere. Thank you

Comment: [FCM is the new improved GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq). What's wrong with fcm.notification.body?

Comment: scripts Im creating are meant to emulate current state - in current state, we are receiving gcm.notification.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hacky but with colleague, we were able to figure out solution to this. Proper payload JSON would be like this:

```
{   
    "to":  "someDeviceToken",
    "data":{
        "gcm.notification.e": 0,
        "gcm.notification.body":{
            "title": "Title supported",
            "message": "Notification Message",
            "type": "example",
            "id": 345,
            "priority": 1,
            "data": {
                "images": [ 
                    "https://someimage.com/image.png"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`"gcm.notification.e": 1` doesn't work - it has to be 0.